# Delete characters from certain parts of varchar datatype

Tags: select, sql-server-2012

I have values in my table like below. This column name is

> ro

```
N3195 (T132 / RL / TB / tgh 44,373 - 1,994)
N13 (T13 / RL / TB / tgh 0 - 12,586)
N9 (T129 / L / V / tgh 10,89 - 21,96)
31 (T129 / RL / WV / tgh 10,89 - 21,796)
```

After the select statement I only want te keep the number after 'tgh' and before the character '-'. The end result must be without spaces. So from the above code:

- 44,373
- 0
- 10,89
- 10,89

I tried using charindex and substring and right and left but I didnt get the right result.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SQL Server` dos not give you much control for this type of search. This is an example how you can tackle this problem. This is a fixed solution that may fail for some strings that are different from ones you provided:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( ro NVARCHAR(MAX) )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 'N3195 (T132 / RL / TB / tgh 44,373 - 1,994)' ),
        ( 'N13 (T13 / RL / TB / tgh 0 - 12,586)' ),
        ( 'N9 (T129 / L / V / tgh 10,89 - 21,96)' ),
        ( '31 (T129 / RL / WV / tgh 10,89 - 21,796)' )


SELECT *, REPLACE(SUBSTRING(ro, 
                            CHARINDEX('tgh', ro) + 3, 
                            CHARINDEX('-', ro) - CHARINDEX('tgh', ro) - 3), ' ', '') 
FROM @t
```

Comment: I can't get what you mean.

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting that result. You are doing something wrong. I am getting the correct results. Can you make a print screen so I can see what your select looks like and what output looks like?